# How to format an array of dates using datepipe in angular?

Tags: typescript, angular7, date-pipe

I have an array of dates and it would be like

```
      [
        "2019-06-17 09:21:20+05:30",
        "2019-06-18 09:21:20+05:30",
        "2019-06-19 09:21:20+05:30",
        "2019-06-20 09:21:20+05:30"
      ]
```

how to convert this to date time using datepipe.

Answer (score 3):

import the DatePipe to your app.module file `import { DatePipe} from '@angular/common'`

and format your date objects using this [Pre-defined format options](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options)

and include this code to your app.component.html page

```
{{ DateObjectValue | date:'medium'}}
```

see the attached stackblitz example link : [FormatDateExample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkisrc)

Comment: i am doing this for chart purpose.so can this be converted in typescript itself.thats what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe like this

TS file

```
export class AppComponent  {
  yourdate =   [
        "2019-06-17 09:21:20+05:30",
        "2019-06-18 09:21:20+05:30",
        "2019-06-19 09:21:20+05:30",
        "2019-06-20 09:21:20+05:30"
      ];
}
```

HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let item of yourdate">
  {{item | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'}}
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-array?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

StackBliz is here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvpg4r

1) Import DatePipe:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

2) Include DatePipe in your module's providers:

```
NgModule({
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppModule {
}
or component's providers:

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class HomeComponent {
...
```

3) Inject it into your component's constructor like any other service:

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
}
```

4) Use it:

```
ngOnInit() {
     data=this.datePipe.transform("2019-06-20 09:21:20+05:30", 'yyyy-dd-MM');
}
```

Comment: i need in typescript..to dispaly in chart.i was using datepipe.so how to use datepipe for array of dates.

Comment: @minnu Please Check the Edited code Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: i have an array of dates..do i need to loop the array ?or any other way

Comment: Yes of course loop the array and push your converted date into new array